# What does "type name{}" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

I found the following construction in the source code:

```
variable_type variable_name{func(arg1, arg2, arg3)};
```

In the next version of the code this construction has been replaced by the following one:

```
variable_type variable_name = func(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

So, my question is what the first line mean and how is it different from the second line? I also would like to know why it might be better or worse to use the first line instead of the second one?

Comment: In this case, it is the same. See [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm)

Comment: @Mat I think that is not the right duplicate, since it deals with classes with initializer_list constructors.

Comment: The details of what goes on depend on the constructors of `variable_type` and on the return type of `func`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an example for a C++11 brace initialization.

See for example the following article:

https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519

Comment: No, it isn't, it applies to non-container types too.

Comment: Right, changed it to "brace initialization".

Answer (score 1):

The first line is a new feature from C++11 known as [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization). This style of initialization can also be used on classes which define a constructor that takes an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), in which case such a constructor takes priority.